# Tomcat connector failed to start but port is bound

Tags: java, tomcat

I get the following error when I try to initiate Tomcat connector on port 443 :

```
16-Jul-2018 09:30:08.394 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-443]]
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-443]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:549)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:875)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:632)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:655)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:309)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
```

I expect this error and knows why it occurred.

The issue is that although the connector has failed to start, it seems that Tomcat is still listing on port 443 and every message sent to this port hangs until I get read timeout.

How can i configure Tomcat not to listen when connector failed to start ?

Comment: Functionally speaking, why is this important to you?  If your web server doesn't start up, your users still can't access the site.  Fix the error and move on.  Also, minor thing, the past tense of `bind` is `bound`, not `binded` :)

Comment: 10x, Its important, since i have another Server tries to speak with this one. And it hangs.

Comment: Upvoted.  I have always been terrified of Tomcat errors, but the good news is that you know what is causing this.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment... but still, the configuration related to the ports ins't in the server.xml file?

Something like this?

```
<!-- Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8180 -->
<Connector port="8180" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
           maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
           enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
           connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" />
```

Look up for the 443 port and modify it?

Comment: modify to what ?

Comment: To a no used port, like 8443 or 9433 or 1433 or what port you would like to use and is not used in your environment, and point the other communications to that port. The error you describe, sounds like the port 433 is already in use. Regarding, that even if tomcat is running doesn't mean that it works properly. You should fix all the errors first.

Comment: This is not my use-case, port 443 must be defied.